# Obtener valor textarea de un modal dinamico jquery

Tags: jquery

Buenas estoy intentando obtener el valor de un textarea colocado en un modal dinamico. Pero me devuelve todo el rato `undefined`.

El input del modal.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="" class="labelModal">Concepto</label>
  <textarea name="concepto" id="concepto_{{ $revision->id }} " class="form-control" rows="8">{{ $revision->concepto }}</textarea>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btnGuardar66 editarRevision" data-user="{{ $revision->id }}">Guardar</button>
```

El Jquery.

```js
$('.editarRevision').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('user');
    var Fecha = '#lafecha_' + id;
    var Concepto = '#concepto_' + id;
    var IdRevision = '#idRevision_' + id;
    fecha = $(Fecha).val();
    concepto = $(Concepto).val();
    IdRevision = $(IdRevision).val();

    console.log(fecha, concepto, IdRevision);

    var misDatos = {
        "fecha" : fecha,
        "concepto" : concepto,
        "revision" : IdRevision
    }
    console.log(misDatos);
    return false; 
});
```

Pero me devuelve esto:

```
"3"}
concepto: undefined
fecha: "2020-11-26"
revision: "3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Acabo de probar tu código, al parecer tu JS funciona correctamente y creo que lo falla realmente es la declaración del `id` en tu `textarea`. Tienes el operador `->`, por lo que deberías de contar con la declaración de la siguiente forma:

```
<textarea id!="concepto_{{ $revision->id }} " rows="8">{{ $revision->concepto }}</textarea>
```

Usando el operador `!` antes del signo `=` para que soporte el operador `->`.

No sé en verdad por qué no falla la página antes desplegar los campos, ante la falta del `!` pero es mi mejor intento de descifrar lo que pasa.

Te dejo la prueba funcionando correctamente [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/kr09huqs/1/)

Comment: Hola acabo de probar lo que me dices, pero sigue pasando lo mismo. No se que pasa por que no me coge el valor :S

Comment: Verifica el ejercicio que te mandé, compáralo con lo que tienes. Inspecciona tu vista y verifica que los operadores "->" estén funcionando correctamente y desplegando la información que deberían